# SSAS IgnoreUnrelatedDimensions and Grand Total behaviour

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, ssas-2012

I'm stuck on some things. If F Qty is selected I want Sales Line Selling Quantity to repeat.  I don't want to change the global setting 'IgnoreUnrelatedDimensions' (as we have lots of users using this measure and it will affect all their spreadsheets) is it possible to do this in MDX in the 'calculations' tab?

Also I don't want F Qty to aggregate (basically you can have multiple forecasts at multiple months) so summing them doesn't make sense.  They still want to analyse F Qty side by side against Sales Line Selling Quantity.  Is it possible to turn off or hide the grand total for a column?  If not, how can I display the last value that isn't a 0 as a grand total?

Also if I can get the Sales Line Selling Quantity to display my forecast accuracy calculation should work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide the aggregation of F Qty I would use a SCOPE calculation, something like this:

`SCOPE ( [ForecastOffset].[ForecastOffset].[All] , [Measures].[F Qty] );
     This = null;
END SCOPE;`

I'm guessing the dimension name for the ForecastOffset attribute.

This should appear after the definition of [Measures].[F Qty] (if one exists in the Calculated Measures script).

For Sales Line Selling Quantity another SCOPE calculation might work, e.g.

`SCOPE ( [ForecastOffset].[ForecastOffset].[All].CHILDREN , [Measures].[Sales Line Selling Quantity] );
     This = [ForecastOffset].[ForecastOffset].[All];
END SCOPE;`

Comment: hi thanks for your help i will try that.  How do I use the validmeasure function to override the ignoreunrelateddimensions property and repeat the value as asked above?

Comment: I have another question posted based around mdx if you fancy killing two birds with one stone! I am new to mdx.

Comment: Presumably Sales Line Selling Quantity has an existing MDX calculation?

Comment: hi sorry for delayed response, no it is just a standard sum measure

Comment: So why doesn't it show any values against the rows?

Comment: Because ignoreunrelateddimensions is set to false. I want to override this property in mdx if they're using f qty

Comment: I've had a go - HTH

Comment: Hi I'll have a look... I have one more question that I'm stuck on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810702/ssas-mdx-line-quantity-divided-by-sum/37812615?noredirect=1#comment63152244_37812615 Be much appreciated if you had a chance to look at that as well! Thanks so much.

Comment: Mike you're a genius.  Can you help me with my other question as mentioned above?