# ssas mdx line quantity divided by SUM

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx, ssas-2012

How do I create the new column in MDX?  The dimensions selected are not important.  I just want the line amount / sum for the data selected.  I am not an mdx expert...

[image]

[image]

Current code below :

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Weight]
 AS IIF([Measures].[Sales Line Amount AC Budget hidden] <> 0,
Divide([Measures].[Sales Line Amount AC Budget hidden]
 ,AGGREGATE(Root(),[Measures].[Sales Line Amount AC Budget hidden])),NULL), 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Sales Forecast'  ;
```

Hi they are the same column... I just reference a hidden column so i can change the properties on it not affecting the original measure. Are you sure the MDX will give me the result I want?  Could it be a formatting issue? the format of that measure is #,0.00

[image]

Comment: I tried something like this [Measures].[Sales Line Amount AC Budget hidden] / SUM([Measures].[Sales Line Amount AC Budget hidden].allmembers) but it didn't work...

Comment: Is the "Sum Below" figure the natural sum of Sales Line Amount AC Budget hidden ? It looks like the row values are duplicated, perhaps there is no relationship to the source dimension for ForecastOffset ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK! 
I think i understand what you want try this. With [Root](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146076.aspx) you can get the All from all dimensions.

```
Divide(
  [Measures].[Sales Line Amount AC Budget hidden]
 ,AGGREGATE(
   Root()
  ,[Measures].[Sales Line Amount AC Budget hidden]
  )
)
```

EDIT:

Don't think there is a fairly easy way to do that. Maybe have a look at [Axis(1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145531.aspx) instead of root.

**I did not try this in a cube only within a query... and it works..**

```
Divide(
  [Measures].[Sales Line Amount AC Budget hidden]
 ,AGGREGATE(
   Axis(1)
  ,[Measures].[Sales Line Amount AC Budget hidden]
  )
)
```

EDIT2:

Since you want this to work with Excel. There isn't a clear way to make it work without knowing exactly which dimensions you want to "Weight".
Excel Works with Subcubes, that means, the Axis function actually return ALL the members from that axis.

There isn't a way to know exactly which members are being actually shown in MDX. This should be a Client side calculation.

You can actually do this very easly in EXCEL simply by selection the field going to OPTION and going to "Show Values As". With "% Grand Total" will give you exactly the percentage you are looking for.

[image: Excel - Show Values As]

Comment: (upped) for seeing `ROOT` ...rare indeed.

Comment: @whytheq I have never used it in production... xD

Comment: Hi it seems to be giving weird results... I've posted an updated pic.  Can you help??? Thanks it's quite urgent i get this working... thanks.

Comment: thanks for your help i will try that.  If that does not work i will have to limit the calculation to certain dimensions being selected would that make it easier?

Comment: There isn't a straight foward way that i'm aware of, to know exactly which members from which dimensions are being shown dinamicly other than Axis function. So there isn't a way to know which member are your current "Total" maybe @whytheq can help.

Comment: axis gave exactly the same  results as root.  I can say ok when company, forecast offset, and month selected then do the calculation, i just have to get it working one way or another.  This is easy to do in SQL, or excel probably.  I don't see why it's so hard in MDX i thought the whole point of MDX was you could do very powerful things with displaying the data. and why aggregate instead of SUM?

Comment: really appreciate the help people are starting to shout about it i'm pretty stuck.

Comment: @jhowe can you add `[Measures].[Sales Line Amount AC Budget hidden]` to the pivot table? In your screenshot you've got G5/G18 but this is a different measure - best you first check the value of `[Measures].[Sales Line Amount AC Budget hidden]` to try to work out where those strange values are coming from.

Comment: The values are probably correct, Root is giving you the SUM of the measure for All the cube, and not only the members selected in the pivot.

Comment: then i need to figure out a way for it to give me the correct value for the members selected...

Comment: @whytheq G5/G18 is simply dividing the line qty by the sum of the selected measure

Comment: @jhowe certainly if you can deliver this in SQL or Excel I would go for that option. MDX is a nightmare.

Comment: @MikeHoney I see you're still preaching the same old line! `MDX is a nightmare` - in the context that jhowe is putting forward it is not really practically possible - but to create measures in mdx which are dynamic, on the fly, is possible: it is just that jhowe is asking for (in my opinion) an unreasonable degree of dynamicness. It might be possible in excel using lookups. It certainly it isn't possible using sql alone - in fact sql is very poor at dynamic.

Comment: I did try this in a cube, it works as expected when i write my own MDX, and i declare the member on axis(1). For reporting purposes it would work. But for Self-Service with Excel, it doesn't due to the fact Excel has it's own way of building with alot of subcubes and Hiearchizes and drilling.. This will make Axis return the wrong members. But for your own queries, either with a Cube calculated member or a query member it works as expected. But client side is the best option. Excel can even do it out of the box.

Comment: hi @mxix can you provide a working example and I'll see if they'll go with this... I don't currently understand how what you're saying will give me what i want.

Comment: The Excel option is the only that will give you exactly what you want... Just add that measure to your columns [Right Click] on the measure column [Show Value as]->[% Grand Total] OR [% Column Total].